# Saving random values into 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays

How do you print and save random values in array using Random.
So I need to have 10x10 table of rows containing random values from 0-9 but I seem to can't find a way how to get them printed!

```
        int[,] mas = new int[9,9];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i <mas.Length; i++)
        {
            mas[i] = rand.Next(0,9);
             Console.WriteLine(mas[i]);
            for (int k = 0; k < mas.Length; k++)
            {
                mas[k] = rand.Next(0,9);  
              Console.WriteLine(mas[k]);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a small issue in your code: The array you create has two dimensions (int[9,9]). Therefore, whenever you want to read or write a cell, you need to provide two coordinates. You only set mas[i] or mas[k].

You should use `max[i,k]` instead in the inner loop. That way, every combination of coordinates will be tried out.

Unrelated: You mention you want a 10x10 grid of cells, but declare `int[9,9]`. While array indexing starts at 0, the size starts at 1. For example, if you create an array a = int[2], then it only contains entries at int[0] and int[1].

Similarly, the maximum parameter of the `Random.Next(...)` function is exclusive, so to get the value 9, you need to pass the maximum value 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you want **2D** array (i.e. you have **two** coordinates: *lines* - `i` and *columns* - `j`), *nested loops* is usual choice:

```
    Random rand = new Random(); 

    int[,] mas = new int[9, 9];

    for (int i = 0; i < mas.GetLength(0); ++i) 
      for (int j = 0; j < mas.GetLength(1); ++j) 
        mas[i, j] = rand.Next(0, 10); // 10 will not be included, range [0..9]
```

Let's print the array:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.GetLength(0); ++i) { 
      for (int j = 0; j < mas.GetLength(1); ++j) {
        Console.Write(mas[i, j]);
        Console.Write(' '); // <- delimiter between columns
      }

      Console.WriteLine();  // <- delimiter between lines
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, note that mas.length returns the overall length of the array, which will give you an IndexOutOfRangeException using your Code. Use mas.GetLength instead of mas.length

myArray.GetLength(0)  -> Gets first dimension size

myArray.GetLength(1)  -> Gets second dimension size

So your Code would look like this:

```
int[,] mas = new int[9, 9];
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < mas.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < mas.GetLength(1); k++)
    {
        mas[i, k] = rand.Next(0, 9);
        Console.Write(mas[i, k] + " ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably like this

```
int[,] mas = new int[10, 10];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < mas.GetLength(1); k++)
            {
            mas[i,k] = rand.Next(0, 9);
            Console.Write(mas[i,k]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
```

There are many things wrong with your code,

You dont know how indexing works - you want array of 10 times 10 but you create one with 9 times 9.

You need to specify both dimenstion when adding number to array.

Also,

```
Consolo.Writeline(string);
```

Will always write new line, something you dont want since you want to print 10 numbers, then new line with another then etc.